# Loading module/chunk from another webpack project

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

I'm currently in process of using webpack to build my javascript application.
The application consists of several separate project/microapplications. Each of them has an independent release cycle. 
How can I load modules from different project/application using webpack?
Can I use import() functionality?

Comment: Yeah, as long as you install the packages from a local source

Comment: Is it possible to load module in runtime/dynamic?